# How to update GCC in MinGW on Windows?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw

I'm used to manually install GCC from source before on Ubuntu and it was a painful process. So I really don't want to do repeat this process. Currently, I have MinGW and GCC (4.6.2) installed on my machine. So is there an easy way to update GCC without building it entirely from source? Has anyone done it before can share me some tips?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Snapshots and release builds of the MinGW http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/list

Comment: Is it OK to simply unzip the x86_64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.0-release-c,c++,fortran-sjlj.zip and put into current MinGW installation?  Will this break something because of library incompatibility?  Does it basically disables mingw-get so that it no longer tracks update for gcc?

Comment: As linked in @GravityWe11's answer, MinGW-builds has moved to [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/). You'll see already a few newer releases here such as GCC 4.7.2 builds. Just adding an update for any future users.

Comment: You can also directly go to MinGW official website from http://www.mingw.org/ and select download to choose the required download from

Answer (score 125):

**Update using terminal:**

1. Run the command prompt/terminal (`cmd` or `sh`).
2. Update the package list:

   ```sh
   mingw-get update
   ```
3. After updating the package list, run:

   ```sh
   mingw-get upgrade
   ```

When the command finishes running, all of your packages will be upgraded.

---

**Update using the GUI version:**

If you aren't used to the terminal, there is also a GUI version of MinGW called "MinGW Installation Manager", which is normally located at:

```
C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\guimain.exe
```

1. When the GUI is open, tap `Installation -> Update Catalogue`. This will update the package list.
2. After that, tap `Installation -> Mark All Upgrades`. This will select all of the packages which can be upgraded.
3. Finally, tap `Installation -> Apply Changes` to apply the upgrades.

Comment: ´mingw-get upgrade´ crashes ("[...] has stopped working."). Any idea why?

Comment: For reference: You can also launch the GUI version by just typing mingw-get without arguments

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE: As of Nov-5-2012, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) includes 4.7.2 of the GCC compiler, which is the most current version. I personally will use the MinGW package, since it includes [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) and other tools, and since it is the defacto standard, I hope that it is better supported. The only drawback is the included GDB does not include Python scripting, but I think that can be updated separately.

---

I don't know if you can update the GCC in MinGW, but there are alternative projects to MinGW with newer versions of GCC.

The [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) project provides a package similar to MinGW but with an updated GCC (4.7.2). I extracted the files to c:\MinGW (so I could use the same path) after moving my existing MinGW to another folder. Only MinGW has [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS/), so if you need that (I did) copy the msys folder from the original MinGW.

After installing MinGW-builds, the result of g++ --version:

```
g++ (Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.7.2
```

The latest GCC that comes with standard MinGW is currently 4.7.0. I compiled a few simple projects in Code::Blocks, and the latest wxWidgets source, and everything seems to work.

It's worth noting that MinGW-builds includes a Python script enabled version of GDB, in case you want STL pretty printer support, or other [GDB Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html) features.

Another good choice is [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), which is a project that hosts an impressive installer that includes an updated GCC compiler (4.7.1) and support tools. It is a standalone package. As far as I can tell, Python scripting is not supported in the GDB that comes with this package.

Finally there is the [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) project, which is a fork of MinGW. Rubenvb, who posted an answer to this question, has good standalone packages (in the personal builds folder) based on this project which include an updated GCC (4.7.2). The included GDB seems to be Python script enabled.

Comment: At this moment, MinGW-w64 includes latest GCC version: 5.1.0 . I would say it is the best option after compiling everything yourself.

Answer (score 11):

if you use [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/)
just open mingw64-console and type in:

```
# Update the package database and core system packages with:
pacman -Syu  

# If needed, close MSYS2, run it again from Start menu. Update the rest with:
pacman -Su
```

Answer (score 4):

I have built a more up to date GCC 4.7 (it's built within code freeze, so it should be equivalent with the release). Also, this build contains `<thread>` support.

- [32-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/4.7.0-3/)
- [64-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/4.7.0-3/)

The *-gcc*_linux package is what you want if you want to use it on Linux. Just extract somewhere and add the `mingw??/bin` directory to PATH.

PS: There's a native Windows compiler and a Windows Clang build. I suggest using Clang only with one of my GCC 4.6 builds, as it has trouble with GCC 4.7's libstd++. Extract the Clang package in the same directory as the GCC package and it will work out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

The MinGW-w64 build from http://winlibs.com/ has the latest GCC version and requires no installation, just unzip the download. To upgrade you can just replace the mingw32 or mingw64 folder with the new version.

Answer (score 2):

To get latest MinGW64 in Windows: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=typ_redirect

For all platforms: https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download

Answer (score 2):

You just need to update your g++ compiler if its not.

First problem can be solved through this:

**Update using the GUI version:**

If you aren't used to the terminal, there is also a GUI version of MinGW called "MinGW Installation Manager", which is normally located at:

C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\guimain.exe
When the GUI is open, tap

```
Installation -> Update Catalogue
```

. This will update the package list.

After that, tap

```
Installation -> Mark All Upgrades
```

. This will select all of the packages which can be upgraded.
Finally, tap

```
Installation -> Apply Changes
```

to apply the upgrades.

**2nd Problem could be that if you didn't updated the path of mingw in environment variables.**