# Compilation error: "stddef.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

Whenever I try to compile this code it always ends up with this error:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:6:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/cwchar:44,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ios:38,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/ostream:38,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream:39,
             from test.cpp:1:
    /usr/include/sys/reent.h:14:20: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
    #include <stddef.h>
                ^
    compilation terminated.
```

The code I was trying to compile is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World! :D";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: try `g++ file.cc` where file.cc is the name of yoru file (should end in `.cc` or `.cpp`). If you still get the same error then your compiler installation is broken; fire up the Cygwin installer and refresh your installation of g++. Check that `gcc` and `glibc` are up to date also.

Comment: @Chol Nhial I compile the code with using the command: g++ test.cpp I also tried g++ test.cpp -o main.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: I've re-installed g++ but it still gives me that error, where can I find the gcc and glibc?

Comment: In the cygwin installer, same page as g++

Comment: I can't find it, am I even looking at the right place?                                         http://i.imgur.com/pyd9FZU.png                                                             Edit: fail, I can't post the image, I'll just post a link with it...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The error is because your gcc-core package and gcc-g++ are not of the same version. Either downgrade one of them to solve the problem or update both the libraries. Updating both the libraries is the recommended way.

Comment: How is that even possible? How does the setup program manage to install the wrong versions of packages on a fresh install? Also how do you perform the update? I'm running setup again, and there does not appear to be an option to update anything.

Comment: If you are using [Babun](http://babun.github.io/), `pact update gcc-core gcc-g++`.

Comment: Still relevant today - installed gcc-core and gcc-g++ for the first time on an existing Cygwin install, and it installed a back level version of gcc-g++, I had to re-run setup.exe and it updated it.

Comment: cygwin package manager apt-cyg or sage: `sage remove gcc-core gcc-g++ && sage install gcc-core gcc-g++`

Comment: From **MinGW Instalation Manager** I upgraded *mingw32-gcc-g++ 4.9...* to *mingw32-gcc-g++ 5.3.0-2* and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are using Babun and @nishpatel's answer did not work for you, try also run `pact update cygwin-devel`.

Comment: As per this answer, just use http://www.mingw.org instead of Cygwin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470379/c-not-compiling-in-netbeans?noredirect=1#comment74060877_43470379

Comment: Perfect!  I had some packages at 7.04 and others at 6.04.  When I downgraded to 6.04 it all worked.

Comment: +1. I was having this problem when building packages for Slackware 14.2 through SBopkg tool, found your solution, implemented it, and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

I had this error on a fresh MinGW install, it had nothing to do with the installed packages mentioned in the current accepted answer by "Prasanth Karri". In my case **the issue was caused by `-nostdinc` in my Makefile**. I actually only needed that compiler flag when building for a different target platform (not when using MinGW) so I fixed the issue by removing that flag from MinGW builds.

Comment: Where is the answer of "Prasanth Karri"?

Comment: Probably the still-accepted [answer by "ThisIzKp"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32410193/1390430). Sorry that past me didn't feel the need to link it. :-(

Answer (score 4):

In order to update it, follow below.
If you are on Windows, just run these on command prompt or powershell

Update the package list: `mingw-get update`

After updating the package list, run: `mingw-get upgrade`

Source: [How to update GCC in MinGW on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865319/how-to-update-gcc-in-mingw-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

When I was incorporating a software library written in C into an existing demo project(used a C++ mbed library) I encountered this problem. The demo project would compile just fine, but after I replaced the existing main file by my own, this error occurred.

At this point I hadn't yet thought about the fact that the mbed library that I needed was written in C++. My own main file was a .c file that `#include` the mbed header file. As a result I used my normal C source as if it was a C++ source. Therefore the compiler that was used to compile my main file was the *C compiler*.
This C compiler then encountered a `#include` of a module [that actually does not exist](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/) (within its scope), as it's not a C++ compiler.

Only after I inspected the output of the build log I realised the various source C and C++ files were compiled by more that 1 compiler(the c++ compiler). The project used used compilers arm-none-eabi-c++ and arm-none-eabi-gcc (for embedded systems) as seen below.

Compile log:

```
Building file: ../anyfile.cpp
Invoking: MCU C++ Compiler
arm-none-eabi-c++ <A lot of arguments> "../anyfile.cpp"
Finished building: ../anyfile.cpp

Building file: ../main.c
Invoking: MCU C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc <A lot of arguments> "../main.c"
In file included from <Project directory>\mbed/mbed.h:21:0,
                 from ../main.c:16:
<Project directory>\mbed/platform.h:25:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Of course in a C++ environment [cstddef exists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/), but in a C environment cstddef doesn't exist, [in stead it's just C's implementation of stddef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct1as7hw(v=vs.80).aspx).

In other words, cstddef does not exist in the C compiler.
I resolved this problem by renaming my main.c file to main.cpp and the rest of the code compiled smoothly too.

**TLDR/Conclusion**: When building a C++ project, avoid mixing C files with C++ files(sources and headers). If possible **rename .c files to .cpp** files to use the C++ compiler in stead of the C compiler where required.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved for me as I installed `codeblocks` with mingw compiler then I copied the mingw folder from codeblocks to C drive and added 
`C\mingw\bin` to the  environment variables.

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Please edit your question so that it explains why it might be working. For more, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you try to compile and see a message like, "fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory", the error is because your gcc-core and gcc-g++ packages are not of the same version. Rerun the Cygwin install and make sure that you select the highest numbered versions of gcc-core and gcc-g++.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the C++ compiler with MinGW I encountered this problem as well. Apparently, you have to also install mingw32-base. Go to C:/MinGW/bin/mingw-get.exe (my path) and check it for installation at the Basic Setup tab.