# Cygwin g++ compilation fails

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am trying to compile a c++ file using cygwin. I get the following error :

> fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory #include

This link provides a solution : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600600/compilation-error-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

But even if I upgrade gcc and g++ package from the UI(setup.exe) it still gives me the same error.How to fix this? How to upgrade it from the cygwin command line?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post your code (at least the beginning) and more of the output / error messages.

Comment: If you just care about getting gcc to work you could use the installer from [Qt Creator](http://www.qt.io/download). It will install gcc via mingw and set up everything so it just works. You don't have to install Qt or Qt Creator.

Comment: "I am trying to compile this code".  Which code?  Shows us the #include line.  Also, show us your gcc command line and your environment.

Comment: This is the code :#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char result[10][10] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    int temp = num;
    cout<<temp;
    int numDigits = 1;
;
    while (temp > 0) {temp = temp/10; numDigits = numDigits*10;}
    while (num >0)
    {
        numDigits /=10;
        cout << result[num/numDigits]<<" ";
        num = num%numDigits;
    }
}

Comment: Have you tried Babun?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600600/compilation-error-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

The link you mentioned was the solution I'd used when I came across the same error.
For the second part of the question, if you've worked with Ubuntu et al. you've heard of apt-get, and know how awesome it is. These guys made just that for Cygwin. :) [Link to apt-cyg on GitHub](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg).

After that, it's as simple as:

```
apt-cyg update <your packages>
```

Comment: I updated the gcc-core and gcc-g++ packages,It still gives me the same error.gcc --version gives : gcc (GCC) 5.2.0 and g++ --version gives : g++ (GCC) 4.9.3. How do I know what packages to update?cygcheck -p g\+\+ does not search for g++ packages.

Comment: Since the DMCA takedown has been resolved again (see [this issue post](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/issues/73#issuecomment-225156152) for background), I've rolled back the edit.