# Why can I not compile this C++ file written in Visual Studio in Cygwin?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cygwin

I have written [this C++ file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0s7i.png).

I tested my C++ file in Visual Studio, and I tried to compile it in Cygwin too for practice.

As you can see in the first image, in Visual Studio, it was successful. But in Cygwin, the same file couldn't be compiled. This is what I tried to compile:

```
g++ Coursera.cpp
```

And these are the errors as a result:

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmV4W.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfjOZ.png)

Including a bunch of warnings, there are a lot of messages.
The main errors are:

```
Coursera.cpp:1:1: error: stray ‘\377’ in program
 ▒▒
 ^

Coursera.cpp:1:2: error: stray ‘\376’ in program
 ▒▒
  ^

Coursera.cpp:17:4: error: invalid preprocessing directive #i; did you mean #if?
    c i n   > >   N ;
    ^
    if

Coursera.cpp:19:2: error: ‘u’ does not name a type
    i n t   n u m b 1   =   0 ,   n u m b 2   =   0 ;
  ^

Coursera.cpp:25:2: error: ‘i’ does not name a type
      {
  ^
```

How can I fix these errors? What is the reason for it?

I also tried compiling the same C++ file converted into UTF-8:

```
cd ~
g++ Coursera_UTF.cpp
```

And I got these errors:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/exception_ptr.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/exception:142,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/new:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/vector:61,
                 from Coursera_UTF.cpp:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/cxxabi_init_exception.h:38:10: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stddef.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Looks like the file is UTF-16 (Windows Unicode) encoded.  Use a text editor and save it as UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\377\376 Appended to file (Windows -> Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462340/377-376-appended-to-file-windows-unix)

Comment: I did both of them... :( Failed... I will show u

Comment: @RichardCritten Hi, Thank you for your help.
I Changed it but there appeared another error... Plz See the post

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank your David. I'm trying trying to use that solution but  I don't think it works...

Comment: That's a different error altogether.  File **stddef.h** appears to be missing from your cygwin installation.

Comment: @RichardCritten Visual Studio can save files as UTF-8 but it's a bit tucked away, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  It probably saved the file as Unicode originally because it contained a non-ASCII character.  It doesn't normally do that.  That's still hostile behaviour though, I don't suppose anybody likes it.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you Paul
I do understand what you mean.
But the thing is I can't find that file on my cygwin intstallation packages(on Select Packages)
Do you know what it is?

Comment: Not much in it actually, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stddef.h.html.  Someone else had this problem recently but I can't track down the post.  Maybe cygwin is slightly broken at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, that's a very old link, this one is better: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/.  Also, there's a likely looking post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600600/compilation-error-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory.  Google is your friend.

Comment: `stddef.h` belongs to `gcc-core` try reinstalling the 7.3.0-2 tests version and be sure to have it properly installed with `cygcheck -c gcc-core gcc-g++`

Comment: Related: *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)*

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50551861/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menu, choose *Save As*. In the save dialog will be a <kbd>Save</kbd> button with down arrow. Select <kbd>Save</kbd> with encoding and choose ASCII.

Visual Studio by default uses wide characters when files are created.

Not all other compilers can compile files saved with this encoding.

Comment: Thank you Robert !
I chose Encoding option as US-ASCII-  Codepage 20127
And I got the same error...

10: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stddef.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

this one is the thing I posted.
Do you know What I should install additionally ?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600600/compilation-error-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory#32410193

Comment: And this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762556/cygwin-g-compilation-fails