# QtCreator annotation compiler does not find stdbool.h

Tags: clang, qt-creator, msys2

I'm using QtCreator 4.11.2 , installed via MSYS2, with ClangCodeModel enabled.

Here is my program (this is the result of creating a New Non-QT Plain C Application):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

_Bool a;
bool b;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The .pro file is unchanged from the default:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    main.c
```

The annotation compiler highlights an error saying `stdbool.h` cannot be found.  [image: screenshot of problem]

But it does not give an error for `_Bool a;` , so it is clearly running in C99 mode but has some problem with include paths. The "Follow symbol under cursor" option works, opening stdbool.h.

**My question is:** How do I configure include paths for the annotation compiler or otherwise fix this problem?

I have been unable to figure out how to set options for the annotation compiler or even which compiler binary it is using .  Under Tools > Options > C++ > Code Model > Diagnostic Configuration it lets me add `-W` flags but does not let me add `-I` flags, a red message pops up saying the option is invalid.

Under Tools > Options > C++ Code Model inspector, there are no diagnostic messages, and the Code Model Inspecting Log shows `stdbool.h` being correctly found and parsed, as `msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/include/stdbool.h`.

If I disable the ClangCodeModel plugin then there are no errors , but I would like to use the clang version if it can be made to work as in general it has good diagnostics.

The result of `clang --version` in a shell prompt is:

```
clang version 10.0.0 (https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages.git 3f880aaba91a3d9cdfb222dc270274731a2119a9)
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: F:\Prog\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

and if I compile this same source code using `clang` outside of QtCreator, it compiles and runs correctly with no diagnostics.  So the annotation compiler is clearly not the same as the commandline `clang`?

The Kit I have selected in QtCreator is the autodetected Desktop Qt MinGW-w64 64bit (MSYS2)

The exact same symptoms occur if I make a Plain C++ project and try to include `stdbool.h`  (which is required to exist by the C++ Standard, although deprecated), although interestingly it does accept `<cstdbool>`.

---

I have found a workaround of sorts: including in the `.pro` file the line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += F:/Prog/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/include/
```

causes the annotation compiler to work correctly, however this is undesirable as I'd have to keep changing it whenever I switch Kits because it also passes this to the actual build compiler, not just the annotation compiler.

Comment: I don't have experience with QtCreator, but you could use Process Monitor to see if which Clang is invoked and with what arguments.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with `bool` and `stdbool.h` not found in an imported CMake project. Additionally, I'm also seeing the same thing with `NULL` and `stddef.h`.

Comment: Does [disabling the clang code model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137528/11942268) work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Create file `stdbool.h` in `C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include` and copy paste this code:

```c
/* Copyright (C) 1998-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This file is part of GCC.
GCC is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
any later version.
GCC is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */
/*
 * ISO C Standard:  7.16  Boolean type and values  <stdbool.h>
 */
#ifndef _STDBOOL_H
#define _STDBOOL_H
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool        _Bool
#define true        1
#define false        0
#else /* __cplusplus */
/* Supporting _Bool in C++ is a GCC extension.  */
#define _Bool        bool
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
/* Defining these macros in C++98 is a GCC extension.  */
#define bool        bool
#define false        false
#define true        true
#endif
#endif /* __cplusplus */
/* Signal that all the definitions are present.  */
#define __bool_true_false_are_defined        1
#endif        /* stdbool.h */
```

### Note

Creating a manual file `stdbool.h` works for me but its a sketchy and a temporary solution for now. Don't use this if you feel its too sketcy. I would rather use a alternative solution than this hack if it exist. This solution might not be good but it still works for me.

Comment: Looks sketchy. The file should already exist as `/mingw64/include/c++/11.2.0/tr1/stdbool.h`, there is no need to roll your own.

Comment: It's not my own I just copied it from web because it did not exist in `C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include`. This is the *Clang Code Mode* path MSYS2 qtcreator uses. qtcreator can compile just fine without `stdbool.h` because it uses another path that contain `stdbool.h`

Comment: You are right I also think its sketchy. I would appreciate alternative solution.