# Getting error messages from QtCreator when trying to build hello world program but the code can still be executed

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Im doing another QtCreator setup on a new system, and now Im getting errors when I try to build even a hello world program.Seems something is wrong with my C++ libs of how Qt is trying to put them together. I'm truly stumped here, any suggestions at all are appreciated.

[image: Errors]

Looked at this a bit more, and it is even stranger than i thought. There is build errors on several lines of several of my projects, but they are actually building and can be ran and even debugged! Unknown type name errors on almost every Qt type, but it still works fine.

So I know even less about the issue: many errors, but everything runs fine....

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you tried doing it without the `using namespace std;` and going for `std::cout` and `std::endl`?

Comment: Seems like its trying to compile using a `c` compiler instead of `c++`

Comment: even if i remove all code and leave only the main function and include, i have the same problem. It is something to do with the C/C++ install I think. But i have no idea what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is caused by some changes they have made to the Clang code model( which I do not/never have used ) and apparaently is quite a common issue.

See: https://forum.qt.io/topic/107181/lot-of-errors-but-it-builds-and-runs-successfully/2

To disable go to Help->About plugins and uncheck the Clang code model box.
Restart QtCreator and this will solve it.

Strange.

Answer (score 0):

### Try with QDebug it is much more easy

```
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    qDebug() << "hello beautiful world!" << endl << endl;

    return 0;

}
```