# stddef.h: No such file or directory in CentOS with gcc version 4.4.7

Tags: c, gcc

```
    /usr/include/stdio.h:34:21: error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75

/usr/include/libio.h:53:21: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
```

Can someone please let me know what is going wrong here?

Edit: Now able to complie using "/usr/bin/gcc hello.c -o hello" but I dont want to specify path of gcc everytime. If I do "gcc hello.c -o hello" I get the above error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600600/compilation-error-stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory  check if it is helpful

Comment: can you compile with verbose option (-v) ? For example: gcc -v -Wall hello.c

Comment: @Gil-Mor Not able to. But I am able to complie using cc. I mean "cc hello.c -o hello" but "gcc hello.c -o hello" is not working..

Comment: @user7375520 I mean - can you post the output of verbose?

Comment: @user7375520 Of course you'll get the same error. But you should see verbose output with more info. Or you're seeing the same output when compiling with and without verbose? In any way, post the output of verbose..

Comment: @user7375520 can you check if stddef.h and  stdarg.h actually exist?

Comment: Yes they do exist.. However "/usr/bin/gcc hello.c -o hello" is working fine. But I do not want to specify the path of gcc. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143080/discussion-between-user7375520-and-gil-mor).