# Not able to install python 2.7 in CentOS 6.9. gcc version is 4.4.7

Tags: python, c, gcc

```
$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux2
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/users/some_name/Python-2.7.6':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

> Have the python 2.7 package but not able to install due to below error that I am keep on getting..Is this due to the gcc version that I have? Is it too old?

```
cat config.log
configure:3838: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3860: gcc    conftest.c  >&5 
configure:3864: $? = 0 
configure:3912: result: yes 
configure:3915: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3917: result: a.out
configure:3923: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3930: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5 
configure:3934: $? = 0 
configure:3956: result: 
configure:3978: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3986: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5 
In file included from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/stdio.h:34:21: error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/libio.h:53:21: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from conftest.c:11:
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you install python from the packages provided by your CentOS distribution? To compile from source you need at least the `kernel-headers` package installed.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I want to upgrade to 2.7 version. By default CentOS ships with 2.6.6 version. I already have python's 2.6.6 version installed and want to upgrade to 2.7

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly has to be done. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Verified that I have the required kernel-headers package installed.

Comment: Isn't there a _Python2.7_ rpm in the _CentOS_ repo? Did you try installing it (something like: `yum install python27`)?

Comment: kernel-headers provides `/usr/include/linux/stddef.h`. If you have this file, then gcc is not looking into the right include directories and you have to figure this out.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Yes I have this "/usr/include/linux/stddef.h". What to do then?

Comment: No, @CristiFati, there is *not* a distro-supported Python 2.7 package for CentOS 6, nor, as far as I know, for any of the other members of the RHEL 6 family of distros.  This reflects these distros' emphasis on version stability.  Python 2.7 is the standard Python 2 for the RHEL 7 family, however.

Comment: How did you install `gcc`?

Comment: @user7375520, the `configure` script produces a log containing a lot of details of the run.  In it, you will find information about the test that `configure` attempted unsuccessfully to perform, and what the nature of the failure was.  This is usually the first place to look when an Autotools `configure` script fails mysteriously.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov gcc was already installed with version 4.4.7.. How ever, once I removed and again installed with "yum install gcc". Can u DM me i=on stackoverflow, as this post is getting very long.. Im not getting how to do it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Buddy have already mentioned the contents of config.log file. Would be helpful if you can point out the specifics..

Comment: Continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143096/not-able-to-install-python-2-7-in-centos-6-9-gcc-version-is-4-4-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stddef.h: No such file or directory in CentOS with gcc version 4.4.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717003/stddef-h-no-such-file-or-directory-in-centos-with-gcc-version-4-4-7)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov It cannot be duplicate of above question as that question was also asked by me...but didnt get any reasonable answer. Thats why posted this one with the whole context.

Comment: I cannot immediately explain the error presented, but I *can* tell you that GCC 4.4 is capable of building Python 2.7, as I have personally performed exactly such builds on CentOS 6.  Do you perhaps have a conflicting GCC installed?  What do `which gcc` and `gcc --version` tell you?  Look also into your glibc installation, specifically the glibc-devel package, for this is what owns the system header files in which the error is being reported.

Comment: @JohnBollinger $ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc $ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)