# Bison 3 in windows with or without MinGW

Tags: windows, parsing, mingw, bison

I am working with Bison 3 in a project in an Ubuntu machine and would like to have the same version in my home windows pc. I am currently using MinGW which includes bison 2.4.2. I have tried to update this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865319/how-to-update-gcc-in-mingw-on-windows) instructions and minGW-get which seemed to update certain tools but not bison.

I have also found other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows) on how to install Bison but it is again for version 2.*. Same happens with [gnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bison.htm).

Is there any way of installing version 3 through minGW or without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found Bison 3 [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/files/old_versions/win_flex_bison-2.5.1.zip/download) following update 2 in [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/?source=typ_redirect) sourceforge.