# Unable to run simple std::async and std::future test program. Error: "has initializer but incomplete type." What's going on?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++17, future

I'm trying my hand at asynchronous function calls in C++ using `std::async` in accordance with this official [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/) sample code.

Unfortunately, compilation fails. When running `mingw32-make`, I get the following errors:

- `main.cpp:37:23: error: variable 'std::future<bool> the_future' has initializer but incomplete type`
- `main.cpp:37:61: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::future<bool>'`

I also tried running `make` through WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which essentially makes Linux bash available on Windows. Doesn't work on there either:

```
main.o: In function `std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >, bool>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >, bool>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:122: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

I've tried the following:

1. Updating my compiler using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23804850/10480032).
2. As noted above, attempting to make using two different approaches. Both fail.
3. Using `gcc` instead of `g++` (just a different compiler).

Here is `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <future>


// a non-optimized way of checking for prime numbers
bool is_prime (int x) 
{
    std::cout << "Calculating. Please, wait..." << std::endl;
    for (int i=2; i<x; ++i)
    {
        if(x % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


void interpret_result (bool result)
{
    if (result)
    {
        std::cout << "It is prime!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It is not prime!" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    long num = 313222313;

    // The result of the asynchronous call to is_prime will be stored in the_future
    std::future<bool> the_future = std::async (is_prime, num);

    std::cout << "Checking whether " << num << " is a prime number!" << std::endl;

    // Nothing beyond this line runs until the function completes
    bool result = the_future.get();

    // Interpret the result
    interpret_result (result);

    // So the cmd window stays open
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my makefile (I like to create one for each project just to practice):

```
COMPILER = g++

COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++17 -Wall -g

LINKER_FLAGS = 

EXECUTABLE = async

all: main clean

main: main.o
    $(COMPILER) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(EXECUTABLE) main.o

main.o: main.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c main.cpp

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I'm not sure why this code isn't compiling. I've run through it and cannot identify any errors. `mingw` updated successfully (I restarted my terminal afterwards).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: cplusplus.com is not official.

Answer (score 0):

```
main.o: In function `std::thread::thread<std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >, bool>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >&&)::{lambda()#1}>(std::__future_base::_Async_state_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >, bool>::_Async_state_impl(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<bool (*)(int), long> >&&)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:122: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

This can be fixed by linking with `pthread` library, probably by adding `-lpthread` to your `LINKER_FLAGS`.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for some reason. On bash, it produced a massive wall of error text. Via `mingw32-make`, nothing changed (still fails). I'm signing off for tonight, but I'll be back tomorrow morning to review comments. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing compiler errors (those that your `mingw32-make` produces). Looks like it uses the compiler which has incomplete support of `future` or something. I can't reproduce it with compilers I have locally. As for the linker error (missing symbols from `pthread` library, it could help if you post that "wall of error text", it may provide another hint.

Comment: [Here's](https://i.postimg.cc/wMxx8RJN/image.png) a screenshot. Strange stuff. (The wall of text happened because I temporarily tried using `gcc` again).

Comment: Also tried [these steps](https://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/error-undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux.aspx). No luck! :(