# MinGW32/64 and GCC: Installing and Upgrading on windows using cmd

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I have already installed MinGW32. I want to update MinGW32, GCC, and G++ on the latest available version. I have searched on the internet and overflow but the answers seem to be **outdated**. One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865319/how-to-update-gcc-in-mingw-on-windows), I tried but it shows the same version of MinGW and GCC( latest version is 10.2 and I have 9.2.0) as before.

Moreover, my machine is 64 bit so I want to upgrade my MinGW to MinGW64 but despite lots of efforts and internet searches, I am *unable to get an executable setup for the system*, neither cmd instructors to install. Also, I am unable to discover instructions for its updating to the latest version available( for future purposes)

Please help me to accomplish the above tasks. Also, it would be better if the step by step instructors are provided using cmd. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last version of GCC seems to be 10.1, not 10.2. You can get 10.1 from MSYS2, for both x32 and x64.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am unable to get through MSYS2. I have similar problems of not getting the setup.exe and after installing https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer, I ran the command ```pacman -Syu``` and I am getting the following error ``` failed to prepare transaction ( could not satisfy dependencies) :: installing file system (2020.02-3) breaks dependencies 'msys2-base' required by dash```

Comment: You were unlucky enough to catch a [bug](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2021)... It'll probably get fixed in a day or so. You can wait, or try an older installer: https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/download/2020-05-22/msys2-x86_64-20200522.exe (All packages will be updated anyway, so if it works, it's in no way inferior to the new one.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for comment. But the older installer is still of no use. It also shows the same bug, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Hmm. Try this workaround then: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2021#issuecomment-648181416

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's a caution. XD. I was looking for doing the above thing using cmd. Maybe commands like pip install -Upgrade

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you know how do I add new libraries( such as FFTW3) on MinGW GCC  for windows using cmd? I have looked up many answers on overflow but they seem outdated or either using visual basic as a base.

Comment: This is the best way (at least from what I know), you'll have to settle for MSYS2 shell instead of cmd. `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-fftw` should do it. (Replace `x86_64` with `i686` for the x32 version.)

Answer (score 1):

The MinGW-w64 personal build from http://winlibs.com/ has the latest GCC version (currently 10.1) and requires no installation, just unzip the download.
If you need to upgrade this later you can just replace the mingw32 or mingw64 folder with the new version.