# How to upgrade gcc compiler to latest version

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, build, g++

I have gcc 6.3.0 and to run tensorflow 2.11.0 along with cuda 11.2, I require gcc version 9.3.1, but I just cannot find a simple and straightforward way to do that. Some people say install mysys, other sites point to sourceforge download link, while download links on mingw site point to github repos, I just don't understand how to upgrade this thing.
It would be really helpful if someone could explain it like you are explaining it to complete newbie, step by step.

Last time, I downloaded mysys2 because someone told that it will automatically upgrade gcc to latest version, mysys2 came with a python 3.10, and I was working with python 3.9, and it created a lot of issues, later I had to reset my pc. That's way I just want to know the direct way to upgrade this thing instead of upgrading other software. I also tried by downloading mingw, but the installer available on sourceforge gives gcc 6.3.0 and not the latest gcc.
And what is this cygwin which gives unix like environment, why do i require unix like environment. Even if cygwin can do it easily, I am hesitant to download cygwin, cause i don't want another repeat of tragedy that happened due to mysys2, afterall, installing a complete set of programs that i don't know anything about and will probably never use will only create additional errors.

Comment: Hi @Aniket!  You can use minggw compiler with below commands to upgrade gcc tool chain.                                        1. mingw-get update 2. mingw-get upgrade
 to update the GCC tool chain. We need msys/ming gw compilers as It provides those linux commands to run Tensorflow (built mostly on C++ , extended to Python/other languages) [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23804850/11530462).